# Retrieve information for the same DTO from two different databases

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I tried to make this as simple as possible with a short example.

We have two databases, one in MSSQLServer and other in Progress.
We have the user DTO as it follows that we shown in a UI table within a web application.

```
User

int, id
String, name
String, accountNumber
String, street
String, city
String, country
```

Now this DTO(Entity) is not stored only in one database, some information (fields) for the same user are stored in one database and some in the other database.

```
MSsql

Table user
int, id
String, name
String, accountNumber


Table userModel
int, id
String, street
String, city
String, country
```

As you can see the key is the only piece that link two tables in both databases, as I said before they are not in the same database and not using same database vendor.

We have a requirement for sorting the UI table for each column. Obviously we need to create user dto with the information coming from both databases.

Our proposal at this moment is if user want to apply sorting using street field, we run a query in the Progress database and obtain a page (using pagination) using this resultset and go directly to the MSSQLServer User table with those keys and run another query to extract the missing information and save it to our DTO and transfer it to the UI. With implies run a query in one database then other query based on the returned keys in the second database.

The order of the database could change depending in which column(field) the user wants to apply sorting.

Technically we will create a jparepository that acts as a facade and depending on the field make the process in the correct database.

My question is:
There is some kind of pattern that is commonly used in this scenarios, we are using spring, so probably spring have some out of the box features to support this requirement, will be great if this is possible using jparepositories (I have several doubts about it as we will use two different entitymanagers, one for each database).

Note: Move data from one database to another is not an option.

Comment: Have you looked at Hibernate multitenancy support?

Comment: I already read about it, but seems to be an strategy to retrieve information from two different sources (Spring routingDataSource work similar to this), in this case database, I don't have troubles with that part is more the next step in which I need to sort based on the column, but the column could be in the first or in the second database. so the full information depends in the first query adding the information for a second query

Comment: @Koitoer what is the size of the tables in both databases?

Comment: Size is more than 10,000 records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you need to have separate `DataSource/EntityManagerFactory/JpaRepository`.

There is **no out-of-the-box** support for this architecture in the Spring framework, but you can easily hide the dual `DataSource` pair behind a Service layer. You can even configure [JTA DataSources](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) for [ACID operations](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/).

Comment: Seems that, for now, is there no out of the box support in spring, basically, that makes you the right answer, thanks. Probably in the future this will be a new feature, who knows

Answer (score 1):

As you will always need to fetch data from both databases, why not populate local java User objects then sort these objects (using a comparator with the appropriate fields you want to sort on).
The advantage of sorting locally vs doing the sort in the database query is that you won't have to send requests to the database every time you change the sorting field.

So, to summarize:

1- Issue two sql queries for the two databases to get your users

2- Build your User objects using the retrieved values

3- Use Java comparators to sort the users on any field without having to issue new queries to the database.

Comment: To do that I believe I need to load all the records to the application and sorting in memory, move that data quantity I think is kind of inefficiently

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to find a way to link 2 databases together so that you can utilize database driver features without your code being affected.

Essentially if Progress database can be linked to SQL Server, you will be able to query both databases using a single SQL query with a join on id column and you will get a merged, sorted and paginated result set for your application to display.

I am not an expert in Progress database but it seems there is an ODBC driver for it so you might try to [link it to SQL Server](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P120484).